# using google places api search

Tags: java, android, xml, gps

I am designing an app that displays nearby places, I am using the google places api  search, the problem is the nearby search doesn't return places except when I set the radius to 20000m however radar search displays places even when I set the radius to 500m the but I can't use the radar search because the radar search doesn't return names of places. please help me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the radar search. The radar search will return a `place_id` for each listing, and you can use the `Places API` to get more details about each `place_id`.

For example:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=PLACE_ID_HERE&key=API_KEY_HERE

Comment: thank you so much, and yes the radar search returns place details but i want to display the names on a listview  first and onclick it displays the place details, now it returns a blanck listview but when i click on a position it displays the place details, please what can i do to get the names to appear on the listview?

Comment: How would I get 200+ place names? Wouldn't Google restrict the number of requests to their servers?